# I get error 'Cannot find the app installed on the device. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked' when testing with local device

Tags: ios, ipad, visual-studio-cordova

I updated iOS on my iPad to 11.2.1 and I am seeing the below error when I     launch the app from Visual Studio TACO from Windows machine connected to a local iPad.

***"Cannot find the app installed on the device. Check that the device is    connected, awake, and unlocked".***

My Mac has XCode 9.2 and doesn't have device support files for 11.2.1,   the latest is 11.2 (15C107).
    Could this be due to the missing iOS device support files for 11.2.1 on the Windows machine where VS TACO is installed or, is it due to some certificate related issue?

Since I don't see any certificate related errors in the VS output, I am presuming I got beyond all certificate related issues. Btw, I am using Cordova 4.5.4 and VS TACO 2015.
Are there iOS 11.2.1 device support files that I can download from somewhere ?

As per Apple support I cannot downgrade to an earlier version of iOS on iPad since 11.2.1 is not in beta. Looks like I either need to get an iPad with older version of iOS or find the device support file for iOS 11.2.1 and XCode 9.2.

Really appreciate for any pointers..